# Error setting form array only brings first value

Tags: forms, angular2-forms, formarray

I can't find the problem to set value in my form. It's only brings me the first value and the mistake is ERROR Error: Cannot find form control at index 1
at FormArray._throwIfControlMissing. Does anyone know what the right way would be like?

in my components

```
  public setValueForm(): void {

const values = {
  '_id': this.priceList._id,
  'name': this.priceList.name,
  'percentage' : this.priceList.percentage,
  'allowSpecialRules' : this.priceList.allowSpecialRules,
  'rules' : this.priceList.rules || []
};

this.priceListForm.setValue(values);
}
```

and my html

```
<div class="row tab-content">
          <div formArrayName="rules" *ngFor="let rule of priceListForm.get('rules').controls; let i = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="category" class="control-label">Rubro:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" formControlName="category">
                    <option *ngFor="let category of categories"
                            [value]="category._id"
                            [disabled]="readonly">
                            {{category.description}}
                    </option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="make" class="control-label">Marca</label>
                  <select class="form-control" formControlName="make">
                    <option *ngFor="let make of makes"
                            [value]="make._id"
                            [disabled]="readonly">
                            {{make.description}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                  <label for="percentage" class="control-label">Porcentaje:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="percentage" name="percentage" id="percentage" [readonly]="readonly"/>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="formErrors.percentage" class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ formErrors.percentage }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">                      
                    <label class="control-label">Acción:</label>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="addRule()">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteRule(i)">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

```
    let control = <FormArray>this.priceListForm.controls.rules;
this.priceList.rules.forEach(x => {
  control.push(this._fb.group({ 
    '_id': x._id, 
    'percentage': x.percentage,
    'make' : x.make,
    'category' : x.category
  }))
})
```